# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working. redirects to 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project for a client who has a blog/news page as part of their website. This is all fine however they have requested that they have custom permalinks instead of the standard issue php variables.

I have used the generator at searchfriendlyurls.com to create the rewrite rule. I have added this to my .htaccess file which is located in the root folder of the website however when I click on the link it just sends me to my hosts 404 error page. Any suggestions. .htaccess file below:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force search engines to use domain.example.org.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.example\.org\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.example.org.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^media/news/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /media/news/article.php?article_url_year=$1&article_url_month=$2&article_url_title=$3&article_id=$4 [L]

# Generated for free at SearchFriendlyURLs.com
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you add some examples, what exact link did you click on?

Comment: The link which takes me to the article page is on the homepage and is currently linked to the clean 'pretty' url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another regular expression variation to the mix:

```
RewriteRule ^media/news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /media/news/article.php?article_url_year=$1&article_url_month=$2&article_url_title=$3&article_id=$4 [L]
```

e.g. for URL PATH:  /media/news/2012/11/test-article/1

The rewrite log, if enabled, will show:

```
[rid#7f920b4b00a0/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] applying pattern '^media/news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$' to uri 'media/news/2012/11/test-article/1'
[rid#7f920b4b00a0/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] rewrite 'media/news/2012/11/test-article/1' -> '/media/news/article.php?article_url_year=2012&article_url_month=11&article_url_title=test-article&article_id=1'
[rid#7f920b4b00a0/initial] (3) split uri=/media/news/article.php?article_url_year=2012&article_url_month=11&article_url_title=test-article&article_id=1 -> uri=/media/news/article.php, args=article_url_year=2012&article_url_month=11&article_url_title=test-article&article_id=1
[rid#7f920b4b00a0/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] trying to replace prefix /srv/www/htdocs/ with /
[rid#7f920b4b00a0/initial] (1) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] internal redirect with /media/news/article.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#7f920bcdda00/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/media/news/article.php -> media/news/article.php
[rid#7f920bcdda00/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] applying pattern '^media/news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$' to uri 'media/news/article.php'
[rid#7f920bcdda00/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/media/news/article.php
```

Comment: What's URL have you entered in your browser?

Comment: I entered the clean url into the browser and it still didn't work

Comment: Guessing the URL your entering into your browser is in a format that does not match the RULE above, so unless you share the URL or at least the path portion there isn't anything I can do.

Comment: The URL I entered was http://domain.example.org.uk/media/news/2012/11/test-article/1/

Comment: First off, if you enter: //domain.example.org.uk/media/news/article.php?article_url_year=2012&article_url_month=11&article_url_title=test-article&article_id=1   do you get the page you desire?

Comment: Yes i do get the page that i desire when i enter the long url

Comment: Afraid that needs to be enabled at the system, Apache httpd.conf, level. If you don't have admin access to the server, ask the hosting company in they can temporary enable it for you.

Comment: Okay thanks very much for your help. I shall mark this as the answer as i feel that i am going to have to try and find a way around this.

Comment: Try altering your Options line to: Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks

Comment: No that didn't work either. I have sent a support ticket to my web host to see if they can fix the issue at their end

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your article.php might be expecting `numbers` judging by your query *article.php?`article_url_year=`$1&`article_url_month=`$2* however your RewriteRule *RewriteRule ^media/news/`([a-z]+)`* will only match letters.

Try to replace this line:

```
RewriteRule ^media/news/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /media/news/article.php?article_url_year=$1&article_url_month=$2&article_url_title=$3&article_id=$4 [L]
```

With this:

```
RewriteRule ^media/news/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /media/news/article.php?article_url_year=$1&article_url_month=$2&article_url_title=$3&article_id=$4 [L]
```

And see if it works.

This code will only allow:

- All letters (uppercase and lowercase).
- All numbers.
- Dash (-)

Comment: I have tried changing the expression to the one that you suggested and still to no avail... can i just clarify: the link which takes me to the article page does it need to point to the query or the generated url?